# Using raster calculator inside graphical modeler

Tags: qgis-modeler

I have an issue, which I am struggling with since few hours - I've built a model which aims to make multicriterial analysis based on few vector layers and DEM.

At the step which is problematic for me I have 5 reclassified rasters and they are fine (I checked them), but after the whole process I get following error: "Error executing algorithm Raster calculator 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details". So I'm pretty sure, that my problem is calling those raster layers in not a proper way and unfortunately I cannot find any help in the Internet for this issue.

Below screens of the model.

[image: model]

[image: dialogue window]

There is also another issue - when I use Reclassify values (simple) from SAGA tools, when I prepare the lookup table and close a dialogue window it resets. Any ideas how to fight that?

[image: reclass]